# Doctrine syntax error ;/

Tags: php, doctrine

I need help with this code:

```
$mdl = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->update('Model_CoachsTownsLang ctl')
                ->set('ctl.Coachs_Users_id', '1')
                ->set('ctl.Towns_idTowns', '1')
                ->set('ctl.Langs_idLang', '2')
                ->set('ctl.title', $data['title'])
                ->set('ctl.active', $data['active'])
                ->set('ctl.description', $data['description'])
                ->set('ctl.modyfication', '1')
                ->set('ctl.modyfied_id', $userData['id'])
                ->set('ctl.permit', $data['permit'])
                ->where('ctl.Coachs_Users_id =?', $data['id'])
                ->execute();
```

ZFDebug output error:

**Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near** 'sdfg sdfg , active = 1, description =...

But I look at this code and I see no errors in syntax. I am counting on your help.

Tabla adds structure to the database:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `intelektualnie`.`CoachsTownsLangs` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Coachs_Users_id` INT NULL ,
  `Towns_idTowns` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `Langs_idLang` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `title` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `description` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `modyfication` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `modyfied_id` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `permit` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_CoachsTownsLangs_Coachs1` (`Coachs_Users_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_CoachsTownsLangs_Towns1` (`Towns_idTowns` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_CoachsTownsLangs_Langs1` (`Langs_idLang` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CoachsTownsLangs_Coachs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Coachs_Users_id` )
    REFERENCES `intelektualnie`.`Coachs` (`Users_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CoachsTownsLangs_Towns1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Towns_idTowns` )
    REFERENCES `intelektualnie`.`Towns` (`idTowns` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CoachsTownsLangs_Langs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Langs_idLang` )
    REFERENCES `intelektualnie`.`Langs` (`idLang` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
->set('ctl.title', $data['title'])
```

to

```
 ->set('ctl.title', "'" . $data['title'] . "'")
```

and:

```
->set('ctl.description', $data['description'])
```

to

```
 ->set('ctl.description', "'" . $data['description'] . "'")
```

Comment: oh yeah you were right, and I did not think that the title be changed also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As a thumb rule, enclose every string in quotes when running sql queries.

Comment: This "Doctrine" is misleading; this syntax looks like prepared statements, which apparently it is _not_. So don't forget to escape, too!